# RhinoScriptEngineFactory not found

Tags: java, rhino, scriptengine

I cannot run "hello world" rhino programs with the Oracle JVM's JDK7U10 or JDK6U32, using a main class and ant 1.8.4. I am getting this error:

```
ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngineFactory not found
...
[java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[java]     at com.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

My code is copied from the docs, the error occurs on engine.eval:

```
package com;

import javax.script.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        // create a JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // evaluate JavaScript code from String
        engine.eval("print('Hello, World')");

    }
}
```

I have the rhino supplied js.jar in my lib dir as well as an ant required package I might need, bsf.jar. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but you can try initializing ScriptEngineManager with:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code of this form to discover the engines visible to the JRE:

```
for (ScriptEngineFactory sef : new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineFactories()) {
  System.out.println(sef);
  System.out.append("  Engine: ")
      .append(sef.getEngineName())
      .append(" ")
      .println(sef.getEngineVersion());
  System.out.append("  Language: ")
      .append(sef.getLanguageName())
      .append(" ")
      .println(sef.getLanguageVersion());
  System.out.append("  Names: ")
      .println(sef.getNames());
}
```

I don't think Rhino is automatically visible to the JRE's `javax.script` API (except for the version shipped in Oracle's JDK.)